# UserWarning: The least populated class in y has only 1 members, which is less than n_splits=5

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use Grid Serach for Random Forest on a data frame. The code is below:

```
# Standardization
x=df.iloc[:,:-1]
y=df.iloc[:,-1]
x_cols=x.columns
# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

x = StandardScaler().fit_transform(x)
print(pd.DataFrame(x).head())

# Random Forest 
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
rfc=RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42)
param_grid = { 'n_estimators':[100,200,300],'min_samples_split':[2,3,4,5],'max_depth':[4,5,6],
              'criterion':['gini', 'entropy']}
CV_rfc = GridSearchCV(estimator=rfc, param_grid=param_grid, cv= 5)
CV_rfc.fit(x, y)

print(CV_rfc.best_params_)
```

It's giving me the following error:

> UserWarning: The least populated class in y has only 1 members, which is less than n_splits=5.
> % (min_groups, self.n_splits)), UserWarning)

Can anyone please help me to resolve the error so that I could get right paraments for Randon Forest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) documentation:

> For integer/None inputs, if the estimator is a classifier and y is either binary or multiclass, StratifiedKFold is used.

Since you asked for 5 splits, this means that all classes represented in y need to be represented at least 5 times for them to exist in all splits. If you do not want to use stratified cross-validation, you can use *cv=KFold(5)* instead, which will create 5 groups without stratification.

[Here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_feature_agglomeration_vs_univariate_selection.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-feature-agglomeration-vs-univariate-selection-py) is an example of the use of KFold splitting in GridSearchCV, from the Scikit Learn documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the resolution. What if im using Randomforrestregressor. Should I go for KFold(5) of cv?

Comment: For a regressor, the default behaviour is using KFold (therefore cv=5 will use KFold and work in your instance - even though stratified cross validation is less clearly defined in regression cases). You can still use KFold if you want to have more control over your cross-validation.